# choosing between category and then by many subcategories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, categories, acts-as-taggable

I have some question, I will try to explain.

I want to build categorization, that provides such functions. 
I have some big category such Waste recycling equipment under that is subcategories such choppers then again I have subcategories.

I want to build categorization system that allows when I  create new product chose such route to categories.

I want to know what is the best way to provide such function to my app ?

Any suggestions?

acts_as_taggable provide such functions ?

Thanks !

Comment: or You could just show me way to look , maybe there is different way to do such thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used the gem [ancestry](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) for similar purposes. This would at least provide support in the model layer for the tree structure that you're talking about.

[RailsCasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/262-trees-with-ancestry) has done a tutorial about it.

To play with ancestry, I would recommend using the `rails console`, for example like this:

```
# category.rb

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :name, :parent
  has_ancestry
end

# rails console

~/Rails/CTK/jwbc[master] $ rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.11)
1.9.3p286 > main = Category.create(name: "Main category")
# => created
1.9.3p286 > sub1 = Category.create(name: "First subcategory", parent: main)
# => created
1.9.3p286 > sub2 = Category.create(name: "Sub-subcategory"), parent: sub1)
# => created
1.9.3p286 > main.children
# => Would return sub1
1.9.3p286 > main.descendants
# => Returns sub1 and sub2
1.9.3p286 > Category.at_depth(1)
# => Returns all subcategories, in this case sub1
```

Comment: Can You provide with some demo examples ?

Comment: Where I could try out the structure ?

Comment: so I need to add ancestry to category model ? AAh,  I mistakely added it to Product model :) :(

Comment: Then I if i use category like you showed to me, What would be the way to retrieve Products that are under sub1 or sub2 category ??

Comment: `Product.where(category_id: my_category.subtree_ids)` for example. It will find all products that belong to the selected category or its subcategories.